# Why won't the copy task item work in my msbuild script?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

I have the following code in my msbuild script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0" InitialTargets="Build">  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>

    <SolutionName>CommTrac.Web\CommTrac.Web</SolutionName>
    <SolutionFileName>$(SolutionName).csproj</SolutionFileName>           
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="Building the solution"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionFileName)" ContinueOnError="false" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" />    
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CopyOutput" DependsOnTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>      
      <BinFolder Exclude="*.pdb" Include="$(ProjectDir)bin\**\*.*"/>
      <BuildOutputFolder Include="C:\BuildOutput" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Copying from directory: $(BinFolder)"/>
    <Copy  SourceFiles="$(BinFolder)" DestinationFolder="$(BuildOutputFolder)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

For some reason, it will not copy the files to my output directory. I have tried all the similar 
solutions with other questions that I have seen similar to this issue. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BindFolder and BuildOutputFolder are items, not properties. So you need to reference them using @(BindFolder) and @(BuildOutputFolder) instead of using '$'.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I never even noticed the syntatical difference between the 2.